# grep giving error

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to extract no.s from a file, so I created a script, but grep is giving error:grep: line too long. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong. command is:

`echo $(cat filename|grep '\<[0-9]*\>')`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, which part do you need help with, the "line", the "too", or the "long"?

Comment: I want to know what is the meaning of this error so that I can correct it

Comment: The line is too long. Give it shorter lines.

Comment: lines of file are long or the lines grep is extracting is long?

Comment: The `echo` and `cat` are unnecessary. Try `grep '\<[0-9]*\>' filename`.

Comment: @Shweta - What @Ignacio is trying to say is, the pattern you are matching in the file produces input that is, well, too big for grep to chew on. Can you post the output of `head -n1 <filename> | wc -c` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is line-oriented; it will print matching lines to output. Probably you have a huge line in your file, and the resulting line cannot be converted into a string value by shell, as  `$(`...`)` requires.

First of all, try just `cat filename | grep '\<[0-9]*\>' > results` and see what is in the `results` file. Maybe it's enough.

But if you have multiple numbers in a line and you want to extract them all, use `-o`:  `grep -o '\<[0-9]*\>'`. This will print only matching parts, every match on a new line, even if original matches are on the same line. If you need line numbers, too, add `-n`.